# An active record array of post objects is being returned after my actual post objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am displaying all of a user's posts in my users#show view, and it is working fine except for an array of all the user's posts is being returned after the actual posts.  Here is the show action for the users controller:

```
def show
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @posts = @user.posts.all
end
```

users/show.html.erb

```
<div class="profile">

  <%= image_tag @user.image.url(:thumb) %>
  <h4><%= @user.name %></h4>

</div>

 <div class="userposts">

    <%= @posts.each do |post| %>

    <h8><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h8>
    <p><%= truncate(post.content, length: 250, omission: '... (continued)') %></p>


    <% end %>
</div>
```

Here is the unwanted array being returned:

```
 Post id: 1, title: "post", content: "content", created_at: "2014-12-02 14:07:43", updated_at: "2014-12-02 14:07:43", user_id: 1 Post id: 2, title: "Another Post", content: "more content", created_at: "2014-12-02 14:29:26", updated_at: "2014-12-02 14:29:26", user_id: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this `<%= @posts.each do |post| %>` to this     `<% @posts.each do |post| %>`.

In `erb` `<%=` means the evaluated code will be printed out.